# Assigning random value to each record, not just whole query

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I have written a query which needs to match one of five possible values to around 1500 records randomly for each record. I have managed to get it to assign a value randomly, but the value assigned is the same for every record. Is there a way of doing this without using PL/SQL? Please let me know your thoughts. Query is below (database is Oracle 11g):

```
select
ioi.ioi_mstc
,ioi.ioi_seq2
,max(decode(rn, (select round(dbms_random.value(1,5)) num from intuit.srs_ioi where rownum < 2), uddc))
from
intuit.srs_ioi ioi
,intuit.srs_cap cap
    ,(select
    sub.udd_code uddc
    ,row_number() over(partition by sub.udd_udvc order by rownum) rn
    from
      (select * from
      intuit.men_udd udd
      where
      udd.udd_udvc = 'PA_REJ_REAS'
      order by dbms_random.value) sub
    where rownum <= 5) rejReas
where
ioi.ioi_stuc = cap.cap_stuc
and ioi.ioi_iodc = 'PAPERLESS'
and cap.cap_ayrc = '2013/4'
and cap.cap_idrc like '%R%'
group by ioi.ioi_mstc
,ioi.ioi_seq2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [sub-query caching](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html). Consider the following query and the values returned:

```
SQL> with numbers as (
  2   select level as lvl
  3     from dual
  4  connect by level <= 10
  5          )
  6  select lvl
  7       , ( select dbms_random.value(1,5)
  8             from dual ) as sq
  9       , dbms_random.value(1,5) as nsq
 10    from numbers
 11         ;

       LVL         SQ        NSQ
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2.56973281 2.86381746
         2 2.56973281 3.54313541
         3 2.56973281 1.71969631
         4 2.56973281 3.71918833
         5 2.56973281 3.10287264
         6 2.56973281  3.9887797
         7 2.56973281  2.6800834
         8 2.56973281 3.57760938
         9 2.56973281 2.47035426
        10 2.56973281 3.77448435

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The value is being cached by the sub-query; simply remove it.

```
select ioi.ioi_mstc
     , ioi.ioi_seq2
     , max(decode(rn, round(dbms_random.value(1,5)) , uddc))
  from ...
```

Comment: Could you share more detail in how I would stop this value being cached? Thanks in advance.